# Give Document proper URL or location

Tags: javascript, html, domdocument

I download HTML code using Ajax and then parse it:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Request for the current URL (such as http://example.org or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433215/give-document-proper-url-or-location)
req.open("GET", window.location.href);
req.onload = function() {
   //Returns Document object with `about:blank` in URL
   var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
   //Put the code from request to the Document (all relative URL's are now lost)
   doc.documentElement.innerHTML = this.responseText;
   window.loadedDoc = doc;
}
req.send();
```

The problem is that the document's URL is `about:blank`. This causes any relative URL lead to wrong path. Most importantly, picking `href` from `<a>` gives you `/path/` instead of `http://example.com/path/`.

Can I, at certain point, set the proper `Document.URL`? The url should be the same as current `window.location` - so there's no security risk!

If browser implementations didn't ever thing about this case, is it at least possible to replace link URL's properly?

Comment: The question is, why is the location `about:blank`, and why are you doing ajax request from that, to what, and how are you avoiding the same-origin policy with that ?

Comment: @adeneo Since **when** does CORS apply to **`window.location.href`**? Check the code please.

Comment: It doesn't, Cross Origin Resource Sharing probably has nothing to do with it, but I haven't mentioned CORS at all ?

Comment: CORS is subset of same-origin policy. Which other part did you mean? Which part of it do I seem to violate and how? I'm really just loading the current URL by Ajax. And I need a document with that same URL.

Comment: How are you going to even perform cross-domain AJAX request? They are forbidden.

Comment: What you're doing is just horrible, why would you replace the entire `<html>` tags content. Also, if `document.URL` is `about:blank`, how do you run javascript from that, and how do expect to do ajax do a different domain without having issues?

Comment: And no, CORS is not a subset of the same-origin policy, it's Cross Origin Resource Sharing, which can be a solution to circumvent the same-origin policy

Comment: @adeneo **Please** READ MY POST. Loading anything from **`window.location.href`** does NOT violate anything. It **MUST** be the same origin (heck, it's even the same URL). I'm **NOT** replacing entire HTML. Where did you figure out I'm loading **different domain**? Where this idea pop out? And who told you I'm replacing anything at all? Why do you making this hard for me instead of helping?

Comment: Well, ok, you're creating a new document, so you're not, but why are you doing that, and the value of the attributes shouldn't change to absolute URL's.

Comment: @adeneo I don't understand what are you saying.

Comment: You have a new empty document, and you're giving it the same content as the current page. First of all, why? Secondly, the attributes shouldn't change, you should still have the same URL's, and why wouldn't they work. It's hard to understand what you're doing?

Comment: You don't need to know why - but I'm preloading [webcomic](http://xkcd.com/688/) using AJAX in userscript. So in fact, I'm not loading exactly same URL. And yes, the attributes change. You didn't test anything and you doubt me?

Answer (score 0):

Try sniffing for the `about:blank` string, and do not use relative paths if it is present:

```
var url = window.location.href;

if (url == 'about:blank')
{
    // Use absolute paths
}
else
{
    // Use relative paths, as before
}
```

An possibly more reliable way to perform that comparison might be performed using `String.indexOf()`:

```
if (url.indexOf('about:blank') !== false)
{
    // Use absolute paths
}
```

Comment: `window.location` is not relevant variable. The problem applies to the document I create. `window.location` represent current page's URL.

Comment: I believe you'd already checked its contents. May I ask why it is not relevant/why you are unable to treat it as a string to pass to the request in this regard? This is an interesting issue.

Comment: Because I apply DOM and even jQuery selectors to the document. I'm making a userscript that preloads next page in series (for xkcd webcomic). So I need the links right.